# Hibenate create criteria for Joins on Secondary keys

Tags: sql, hibernate, createcriteria

Is it possible to do something like this with hibernate criteria.

```
select * from A inner join
B on A.customer_id = B.id left outer join
C on A.customer_id = C.customer_id;
```

Table A and C have a attribute `customer_id`,
Table B primary key is `id` which is `customer_id` in table A and table C.

I want to join the result of table A and table B with table C on `A.customer_id` and `C.customer_id`.

I tried doing this:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(A.class, "A_");

criteria.createCriteria(A_.invoiceId, INNER_JOIN);

// Now join table C with A.invoice_id = C.invoice_id
```

Now how to join C?

I am blocked after this as `createCriteria` doesn't ask for parameters on which join should be applied.

Comment: Can you share A, B and C entity  classes